# how to run an onpremise service fabric cluster in docker containers for windows?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am not sure if this is possible, but if it is and someone have the experience to do so, could we not create a docker image for windows that represent an node?

I imaging that we will have a folder with configuration files, that can be mounted with docker -v

then if one needed a 5 node cluster, i would just run

`docker run -v c:/dev/config:c:/config microsoft/servicefabric create-node --someOptions`

for each node we wanted.

Is there any barriers for doign this? have anyone create the docker images for doign so? This would really simplify setting up a cluster on premise.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 6.1 release you can run a cluster in a container, for dev/test purposes.
I'm not sure if you can get it to work with multiple containers though.

> **Service Fabric Linux Clusters in a Container**
>
> We have provided a
> pre-configured Docker container image to run Service Fabric Linux
> clusters in a container. The main scenario is to provide a
> light-weight development experience for MacOS, but the container will
> also run on Linux and Windows, using Docker CE.
>
> To get started, follow the directions here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-mac
> and
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-local-linux-cluster-windows

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, just for windows and the options to spin five up to form a cluster :) would be cool.

Comment: Actually, dont need windows containers when linux clusters can run dotnetcore 2.0 stuff :)